# Show form on mouse hover using Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have written lightning component to display accounts. Can you please let me know how to display popup modal (with Account Name, Description) when keeping the mouse hover on Account name using overlay library component. recordviewform component should be called and displayed as modal when keeping mouse on account name.  Thanks in advance.

**AccountListController.cmp**

```html
    <aura:component controller="AccountListController"
                    implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" >
        
        <aura:attribute type="Account[]" name="acctList"/>
        <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
        
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchAccounts}"/>
        
        <lightning:datatable data="{! v.acctList }" 
                             columns="{! v.mycolumns }" 
                             keyField="id"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
        
    </aura:component>
```

**JS Controller:**

```js
    ({
        fetchAccounts : function(component, event, helper) {
            component.set('v.mycolumns', [
                {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
                    {label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry', type: 'text'},
                    {label: 'Type', fieldName: 'Type', type: 'Text'}
                ]);
            var action = component.get("c.fetchAccts");
            action.setParams({
            });
            action.setCallback(this, function(response){
                var state = response.getState();
                if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                    component.set("v.acctList", response.getReturnValue());
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    })
```

**Server Side Controller:**

```java
public class AccountListController {
        
        @AuraEnabled
        public static List < Account > fetchAccts() {
            return [ SELECT Id, Name, Industry, Type FROM Account LIMIT 10 ];
        }
        
    }
```

**recordviewform.cmp:**

```html
    <aura:component>
        <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{recordId}" objectApiName="Account">
            <div class="slds-box">
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Description" />
            </div>
        </lightning:recordViewForm>
    </aura:component>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am beginner to lightning component. Need help on how to call another component onmouseover event.

Comment: you can achieve by using standard SLDS table instead of `lightning:dattable`

Comment: Can you please help me on that. Bit idea is enough